# Sharing any kind of file with Facebook SDK on iOS?

Tags: sharing, facebook

I would like to allow users to share pdf files created with our app. After doing some research I only find ways to upload images or videos. I cant find a way to upload an arbitrary filetype  to facebook.
Is there a way to do this? I would already be happy if it is just a facebook message with a file attachment or something similar.

Thanks

Comment: Pretty sure you can just include a link

Comment: A link is not a file, right? I want facebook to actually host the file

Comment: That is correct. I don't think that is possible

Comment: Is this possible to share text file on facebook @WizKid